# Why can't I construct `WebAssembly.Memory` in browsers?

Tags: javascript, linux, memory, browser, webassembly

I've stumbled across some weird behavior in all browsers I've tried:

- Chromium 69.0.3497.92 (Official Build) Arch Linux (64-bit)
- Chrome 69.0.3497.100 (Official Build) (64-bit)
- Firefox 62.0 (64-bit)

When I try to allocate memory for WebAssembly by instantiating a `WebAssembly.Memory` object, for example like this:

```
new WebAssembly.Memory({ initial: 1 })
```

In Chrome/Chromium, I get:

```
VM274:1 Uncaught RangeError: WebAssembly.Memory(): could not allocate memory
    at <anonymous>:1:1
(anonymous) @ VM274:1
```

And in Firefox, I get:

```
Error: out of memory
```

The allocation works just fine in Node.js, but for some reason, all my browsers fail here. I'm not sure what to do, and all sites that depend on WebAssembly have since become unusable for me.

I suspect Linux is preventing the browsers (but not node.js?) from allocating the memory, but that's just a wild guess. A near identical installation on another computer works just fine, but on this particular machine, every allocation from a browser fails.

Does anyone know what's going on?

Here's my output of `ulimit -a`:

```
-t: cpu time (seconds)              unlimited
-f: file size (blocks)              unlimited
-d: data seg size (kbytes)          unlimited
-s: stack size (kbytes)             8192
-c: core file size (blocks)         unlimited
-m: resident set size (kbytes)      unlimited
-u: processes                       31215
-n: file descriptors                1024
-l: locked-in-memory size (kbytes)  16384
-v: address space (kbytes)          8388608
-x: file locks                      unlimited
-i: pending signals                 31215
-q: bytes in POSIX msg queues       819200
-e: max nice                        0
-r: max rt priority                 99
-N 15:                              unlimited
```

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a limit that's set in your OS.  On 64-bit systems, the browsers reserve 6GB of virtual memory per wasm memory object (in order to avoid bounds checks in the machine code).  If your max memory is limited you may run into problems with that.  The output from ulimit shows that you're limited to 8GB of virtual address space per process, which probably explains this.

Perhaps try running `ulimit -v unlimited` to see if this improves the situation?

Comment: After running `ulimit -v unlimited`, the command `ulimit -v` still reports `8388608`. Setting it higher than my physical memory is, apparently, not allowed. If I do `ulimit -v 8388609`, I get `ulimit: value exceeds hard limit`.

Comment: Supposedly the system limit on the ulimit is set in a configuration file, /etc/security/limits.conf, and you may be able to edit this to raise the system limit and allow your user process to have a higher limit.  I found one tutorial here: http://geekswing.com/geek/quickie-tutorial-ulimit-soft-limits-hard-limits-soft-stack-hard-stack/ but surely there must be others.

Comment: I've seen a note about this file in the Arch Wiki, particularly on this article: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Limits.conf I'm using `systemd` on my machine, but I have not modified any of the relevant `systemd` files that would control the limit. A few months ago, everything worked, so I'm not quite sure if it's really an OS issue. Why would `node.js` not be affected?

Comment: It's a good question about node.js.  I don't know why it's not affected, it could just be luck with how the virtual memory mapping works out.  Have you tried creating two memories in your test case?  That should blow the 8GB budget even if you're lucky with the allocation for the first one.

Comment: Yeah, I was able to create a couple of hundred `WebAssembly.Memory`s with `{ initial: 1 }` in Node.js, IIRC.